# .txt files to data frame with read_data (RTextTools); error w/ CSV reference

Tags: r, text-mining

I'd like to use the RTextTools package (documented [here](http://dare.ubvu.vu.nl/bitstream/handle/1871/49295/310585.pdf?sequence=1) and on the CRAN manual, to text-mine several documents I've resolved into .txt files. I'm having trouble with read_data()  ([GitHub](https://github.com/timjurka/RTextTools/blob/master/RTextTools/R/read_data.R))

To read text files read_data takes a folder pathname, and a CSV labeling filenames and training values.

In my directory of text files I run this command

```
    df_text <- read_data(filepath = getwd(),type = "folder",index = paste0(getwd(),"/dir-3.csv")

       Error in data.frame(Text.Data = frame, Labels = labels_fixed) : 
        arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 292

       In addition: Warning messages:
         1: In readLines(filename) : incomplete final line found on 'C:/contracts/pdfs/text
```

My CSV file is just two columns that list the filenames I want to read, and a made-up training value I plan to change later:

```
 filename.txt | # 
  x.txt       | 2
  y.txt       | 2
  z.txt       | 2
```

How can I correct these error messages?

Comment: It is to do with your data in txt files. You have different number of columns in txt files it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The function conditions on the relationship between:

```
nrow(labels)
```

which is the number of rows in your CSV and

```
length(files)
```

which is the number of files in the directory.

The easiest way to fix this problem would be to ensure a 1:1 correspondence between files in the directory and files in the index. Barring that, it's something to do with the files in your directory that aren't in your index, hard to tell without seeing your directory.

I'm also suspicious that the second column of your index file may be causing problems. Maybe try getting rid of it or giving it string instead of numeric values?